# Unreal Engine 4. Как сохранить местоположения NPC?

Tags: ооп, сериализация, unreal-engine-4

Недавно увлекся разработкой игр на UE4 и сейчас хотелось реализовать Сохранение и загрузку игры. Для игрока это сделать получилось, но как быть с NPC ? Как взять его местоположение ?

Для реализации этой задачи был создан Blueprint Class и в нем созданы две переменные Player и NPC Transform.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Далее был создан BP_GameInstance и нем несколько методов: getPlayer, saveGame, loadGame и getNPC(пока пустой). И переменная SlotName для вывода результата

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Далее вызываю эти методы у персонажа.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0):

Попал сюда, чтобы самому узнать эту информацию) Но в итоге, спустя 6 часов раздумий нашел один способ.

1. В GameInstance создаешь переменную, у которой тип будет "Pawn"-Class Reference.
   В Default Value подаешь нужного тебе BP (BP_Enemy, BP_NPC и т.д)
   [image: введите сюда описание изображения]
2. Затем создаешь такую функцию для удобства.
   [image: введите сюда описание изображения]
3. Так как переменную NPC Transform ты создал, то уже с ней и работаешь также, как и с переменной Player.

В итоге у меня всё заработало. Но не знаю, правильно я сделал или нет, программирую первый месяц по курсу, до этого даже не прикасался к такой тематике)
Если есть ошибки, готов принять.

Comment: спасибо тебе добрый человек! все отлично работает! Только у меня не получилось в переменной Enemy задать в Default Value его тип, поэтому я просто вызвал Set Actor of Class и в нем задал свой класс противника. Единственное сейчас пока не могу разобраться с сохранением параметров поворота игрока и противника